# :nth-child() and :nth-of-type() not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here's a codepen with my code massively simplified, and it still doesn't work. :nth-child works on the w3schools interactive coding page, so it isn't my computer.

```css
.postPrevWrap:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="postPrevWrap">
  <div class="postPrev">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="postPrev">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dQzYwj

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: `nth-child` refers to element targeted as a child of it's parent.  If you want the odd `.postPrev` target that class.

Comment: Note that pseudo-classes like nth-child apply to elements, not classes of elements, and adding a class effectively turns the selector into a filter.

Comment: a space make a different in a CSS selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:nth-child` should be applied to the child itself, not the wrapper:

So instead of:

```
.postPrevWrap:nth-child(odd)
```

do this:

```
.postPrev:nth-child(odd)
```

Comment: Or `.postPrevWrap > div:nth-child(odd)`

Comment: @j08691 or we simply add a space to his selector